# upload via admin using FileField in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have something very weird. I am on win7 Django 1.4.
I have the following media_root/url settings :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'c:\project\uploads'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My url.py includes :

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

I have a model with the the field :

```
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT, blank = True)
```

Now, I am uploading the file via the admin site, the file is uploaded successfully. however , the when accessing the file via the admin I see the link to the file is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/c:\project\uploads\[filename]
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your model is wrong:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT, blank = True)
```

**upload_to** expects a relative path which is added to the MEDIA_ROOT, so now it expects the file to be at MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_ROOT which makes no sense.

Try something like:

file = models.FileField(upload_to='files', blank = True)

**docs:**

> FileField.upload_to A local filesystem path that will be appended to
>   your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.